# Animation seems to override element position in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created an animation for a `Panel` element in Unity. After that, I've moved the element from its original position.

Furthermore, this element is anchored to the bottom of the screen in order to stay there whichever the screen size is.

The problem is that the moment I hit `Play` to debug, my element suddenly **moves to another position**, which I believe is the original position where it was when I created the animation.

I may be able to create the animation again. However, this would not solve the problem since a different screen resolution would make a slight change to the position, and therefore the desired position for the element to be would be changed again because of the animation.

Can't I create an animation independent from position? In positive case, how? In negative case, how could I address this problem?

Comment: As soon as there is any keyframe for a certain property the `Animator` will always overwrite your script values (Animator is run after all Updates). To avoid it you could e.g. simply turn of the `Animator` while not needed. Alternatively run your positioning in an IEnumerator with `yield return new WaitUntilEndOfFrame` this makes sure that is the last code that will be executed for that frame.

Comment: But then again the moment I turn it on, it would go to the animation position that it's not valid for me at runtime. I need it to be playable on the current position of the element.

Comment: @derHugo could you provide further docs or explanation about the `IEnumerator` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is to make animation relative to a parent object. Put Animator on the Panel's parent, animate its child transform and voila - animation is now always played relative to the Panel's parent position.

https://www.highwaynorth.com/blogs/bryan/relative-position-animation-in-unity

Comment: I'm finding some problems about the child transform. I select the child, create an animation, but there there's no child in the list to add the position!

Comment: You should select the parent and create animation for him, then in the list there will be all your children's properties

Comment: Had to make a fix tweaks aside what it's explained in the link, but the main idea is there. Thanks